# Custom classic ASP 404 page, error reading first variable of querystring

Tags: redirect, vbscript, asp-classic, http-status-code-404, request.querystring

I found a strange situation where Request.Querystring() seems to not work correctly.
I have configured Web.Config to redirect all of the missing pages.

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
    <error statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/404.asp" />
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

It works but the page 404.asp cannot read all the variables in querystring.
To be more specific, the first variable has a messy name.

Let's try to explain better.

I open `http://localhost/IT/?fname=John&lname=Blake` the webserver correctly redirect to 404.asp.

Now the weird. My page 404.asp has access to a messy querystring.

`Response.Write(Request.QueryString())` prints `404;http://localhost:80/IT/?fname=John&lname=Blake`

That is not my original querystring and I cannot find a way to managed it correctly.
Why not?
Because `Request.QueryString("fname")` doesn't return the correct value.

Where is the error? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 404 page receives the URL as a querystring it seems

I would split the result you get which currently stands at `404;http://localhost:80/IT/?fname=John&lname=Blake` using:

```
dim newQueryStringArray
newQueryStringArray= Split(Request.QueryString(),"?")
```

This would then mean that `newQueryStringArray(1)` is equal to `fname=John&lname=Blake`

You can then manipulate that how you want but I'd use a similar approach to the above, using `&` as a delimiter and then the `=` sign to get the value

Try http://classicaspreference.com/aspexamples/custom404.asp